# If() statement not getting called

Tags: java, arrays

```
    public void loseHealth(int amo) {
            if(airID == Value.airTowerLaser) {
            amo = Value.damage[0];
            }
            if(airID == Value.airTowerLaser2) {
            amo = Value.damage[1];
            }
            health -= amo;
            System.out.print(health);
        checkDeath();
    }
```

I have this and now it is working. In my array {2, 900} and yet they both seem to do the same amount of damage. I have been doing some debugging by printing out the values: I have it printing out the right values but it doesn't seem to change anything. I apologize if I am upsetting anybody.

I have done a little more debugging and I have found that the if statements are not being called. I found this by:

```
public void loseHealth(int amo) {
    if(airID == Value.airTowerLaser) {
            amo = Value.damage[0];
            System.out.print(amo);

    }
    if(airID == Value.airTowerLaser2) {
            amo += Value.damage[1];
            System.out.print(amo);
    }
    health -= amo;


            // System.out.print(health);
        checkDeath();
    }
```

If I print outside of the if statement it prints 1 not what is declared in the array. Any help would be fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't work how? do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Does it goes into any of the if-statements?

Comment: Umm many reasons. Param `amo` is zero? `airID` is not == to any of the conditions you have listed, etc.

Comment: It seems the asker hasn't even used a step debugger or System.out.println() to perform basic tests on the variables and branching execution. (This is why I dinged the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Unit Tests with JUnit (assertEquals, etc) or just simple debug statements in every 'if' clause such as "here1", "here2". Also print out each variable if necessary.

Comment: More like a comment than an answer, although I know you can't comment yet. You may want to build rep by responding to better posed questions.

Comment: What do you suggest as a better posed question? Questions that are more obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `amo` into `public void loseHealth(int amo)` and rewrite it here `amo = Value.damage[0];`. It is out of any sense. I suppose you have to pass `airID` into `loseHealth`-method.